# Prerequisites for studying interacting particle systems?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, statistical-mechanics

I am an undergraduate physics student, and I wanted to study about interacting particle systems. I have studied probability theory, linear algebra, and statistical mechanics.

I know basic measure theory and stochastic processes, but have very little knowledge of algebra.

What more do I have to know to study interacting particle systems? (Please give names to some reference books if possible)

Comment: Though this isn't a direct answer to your question, I've found it very useful to learn how to *model* these kinds of things. I didn't feel like I understood the machinery of tensors and manifolds, for instance, until I programmed algorithms to pseudo-display 3D and 2D projections of them. Fluid dynamics and particle systems are especially conducive to such treatment (IMO). There are a ton of libraries for python, old fortran, Mathematica, Matlab, etc. that can help you visualize some of this stuff (except, perhaps, probability theory, which makes mere mortals' eyeballs cross. %-))

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at Talagrand's Mean Field Models for spin glasses:Vol-1. I have started reading it recently. This is more of a Probability theory book rather than a Statistical physics, but it seems quite interesting to me.

Comment: This is a large field. What aspects do you have in mind? Deterministic/stochastic dynamics ? Equilibrium/non-equilibrium statistical mechanics? Continuum models/models on a lattice? Disordered systems? Critical phenomena? (and so on...)

Comment: I have been simulating coagulation fragmentation processes, with special application to biological systems, however I found myself lacking in theoretical background.

Comment: are you still looking for a good reference?

Comment: There are plenty of good notes on interacting particle systems online, but they can be technical. Learning to simulate them using poisson point processes is doable, but the analytical theory is very thick. Look for authors like Rick Durrett, Tom Liggett, or anyone that cites them.